# Translated by Habakkuk 3:3

Tags: translation

אֱל֙וֹהַּ֙ מִתֵּימָ֣ן **יָב֔וֹא** וְקָד֥וֹשׁ מֵהַר־פָּארָ֖ן סֶ֑לָה כִּסָּ֤ה שָׁמַ֙יִם֙ הוֹד֔וֹ וּתְהִלָּת֖וֹ מָלְאָ֥ה הָאָֽרֶץ׃

What is the translation of **יבוא**?

Is it a future verb?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Habakkuk.3.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Machberet%20Menachem&lang2=en

Comment: Why is this different from other occurrences of יבוא (like Gen 32:9, Lev 11:34, and many others), that you ask specifically about this one? Is there something in translations that you've seen that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Habakkuk.3.3?lang=bi)

> אֱל֙וֹהַּ֙ מִתֵּימָ֣ן יָב֔וֹא וְקָד֥וֹשׁ מֵהַר־פָּארָ֖ן סֶ֑לָה כִּסָּ֤ה שָׁמַ֙יִם֙ הוֹד֔וֹ וּתְהִלָּת֖וֹ מָלְאָ֥ה הָאָֽרֶץ
>
> G-d **is coming** from Teman, The Holy One from Mount Paran. Selah. His majesty covers the skies, His splendor fills the earth:

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Habakkuk.3.3?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Habakkuk.3.3.1&lang2=bi) explains this is a reference to the time of redemption when Hashem "will come".

Comment: So יבוא is present tense?